# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError with shared service

Tags: angular

We have a root layout component with child components loaded. De layout component is bound to properties in a shared layout service. De child components set the properties in the shared layout service. Whenever we change properties from a child component we get following error in non prod mode:
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked

This is really annoyting. Is there no other to have this working without doing cdr.detectChanges()?

This is a simple scenario that should work…

```
app.component.html
------------------
<layout>

</layout>

layout.component.html
---------------------
<div *ngFor="let menuItem of layoutService.menuItems">
  {{menuItem.content}}
</div>

layout.component.ts
-------------------
@Injectable()
export class LayoutComponent{
   constructor(public layoutService: LayoutService){}
   ...
}   

layout.service.ts
-----------------
export class LayoutService {
  menuItems: MenuItem[];
  ...
}

child-component-in-router-outlet.component.ts
---------------------------------------------
export class ChildComponentInRouterOutletComponent {

    constructor(private layoutService: LayoutService){}

    ngOnInit(): void{
        this.layoutService.menuItems = [ ... ];
    }
}
```

If in this example I turn de menuItems property into a BehaviorSubject it also doesn't work.

Comment: Data should flow down the tree, and events should bubble up. Sounds like you are making data go up by setting it from within child components. Without code though, there is not much we can do to help you, but I suggest you look into rxjs to get data from services and update them. Maybe even implement redux

Comment: I tried using behavior subject instead of normal properties on the shared service. But even then I get the error.

Comment: There are a lot of examples scattered on the internet on how to prevent it, and like I said before, we kinda need to see the code to see what you've done wrong. Template/service/component

Comment: We have a layout component in the root. This layout component contains a router-outlet. In the router-outlet components are loaded which need to set the layout.

Comment: I added more info in the main post.

Comment: for your use case, you need to use a route resolver, and let the resolver set the data on the `LayoutService`

Comment: It's a framework for 70 or more applications running as one big application for the government. We can't ask them to all do this in a resolve. We just want them to be able to change the layout in a logical matter wherever they want: ngOnInit() after events. It can be any requirement they have. Maybe they want to change the layout after the user click on a button or anything. The layout contains a lot of things to set (submit actions, content actions, menu, help links).This is one of the things in Angular i find really disappointing. In AngularJS this was not an issue.

Comment: Personally i think f#ck this flow of data from parent to child. It should flow in any direction. But thanks for  your help!

Comment: instead of the ngOnInit, try setting it in the constructor, or inside a setTimeout. And the flow of data has a logical reasoning. Single source of truth and whatnot

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing detectChanges on NavigationEnd like so:

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
    }
});
```

With this you are calling detectChanges only once after component has been loaded in the router outlet and after it has set the properties on the shared service.